# Do expired certificates in a Remote Desktop Deployment matter?

Tags: ssl-certificate, remote-desktop, certificate, remote-desktop-services, remote-desktop-gateway

In Server Manager > Remote Desktop Services > Overview > Edit Deployment Properties, all of our RD certificates are Trusted but Expired.  I would expect there to be a warning of some sort when connecting, but we have found this not to be the case.  We're in the process of setting up a gateway and turning off port 3389 on all servers, and are wondering what if any effect the Expired RD certs have, and how important it is we configure new ones?

[image: Expired RD Certificates]